# Navigating to a next page in a gridView

Tags: objective-c

I need help developing a logic that navigates to the next page of a gridView. My current approach takes me to page 2 but does not advances any further than that. 
Here is what I have tried so far.

```
NSInteger nextPage;
NSINteger currentPage;

 UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {        
    CGFloat width = frame.size.width;
    currentPage= floor((gridView.contentOffset.x+width/2)/width); 
    nextPage = currentPage+1; // update the next page button;
}
```

Next page button

```
- (IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame = gridView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * nextPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [gridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple. I added a global variable to track the number of times the nextPage button was clicked and replaced the 
`NSInteger nextPage;` with

int clickedNumber =0;

```
- (IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender {
clickedNumber = clickedNumber+1;
CGRect frame = gridView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * clickedNumber;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[gridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
NSLog(@"%d",clickedNumber);
```

}

This way every time the button is clicked the number is increased and it goes to goes to the next page according the number of times the button is clicked.
 It and works like a charm. :)